# nuxt3 dynamic components not loading in loop

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I have a page that looks like this,

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <NavigationSiteNavigation />
        <main class="">
            <!-- <pre>{{ pageContent }}</pre> -->
            <component v-for="(block, index) in pageContent.page.builder"
                :is="componentMap[block.typeHandle]" 
                :block-date="block.data[0]"/>
        </main>
        <NavigationFooter />
    </div>
</template>
```

I am looking over a response from a headless cms that theoretically building my page from that by loading in the relevant components. However none of the components are loading in, all the components I want to load globally live in `~/components/Blocks` so I added that to my `nuxt.config.js` file,

```
 components: {
        "dirs": [
            {
              "path": "~/components/Blocks",
              "global": true
            },
            "~/components"
        ]
    }
```

What can I do to load in my component dynamically? The nuxt docs talk about loading them like,

```
const mybutton = resolveComponent('mybutton');
```

But surely I don't need to do that? Everytime I add a new component I would need to edit the code?